# oracle (+) operator in where with >(more) or <(less)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, hive

I've read about it and know how it works in this cases

```
select a.id
from a, b
where a.id = b.id(+)
```

but what about this?

```
select a.id
from a, b
where a.id = b.id2(+) and a.id > b.id(+)
```

it is not the same as

```
select a.id
from a
left outer join b
on a.id = b.id2 
where a.id > b.id
```

how would I change it?
I need to rewrite it to hive but hive does not support

```
on a.id = b.id and a.id > b.id;
```

Comment: That's Oracle's old outer join syntax. Either LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN, I can't remember which one.

Comment: @jar my problem is with this part `a.id > b.id(+)`

Comment: @Evgenii - He knows.  He's saying the syntax using (+) is outdated and has been replaced by the ANSI-92 standard syntax using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  This makes it easier to write, easier to read, and easier for the DBMS to reliably generate a plan *(The old notation for outer joins is deprecated because it doesn't always work.)*

Comment: @Evgenii - What version of Hive do you have?  Older versions only support equality joins `=`.  Let's check if that's the problem before looking at alternative solutions

Comment: @mat Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.3.0-235.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins : You have a version that doesn't support `>` in joins *(Requires v2.2.0 onwards)*.  Please give a material example of the logic you are trying to achieve with example data and example results.  There may yet be a way forward.

Comment: @Mat Tried Gordon's answer. It works for my case.

Comment: Good news!  *[ Though I am confused as to why you were trying to join anything if **not joining** is good enough ;) ]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not exactly the same (there are some edge cases), this might do what you want:

```
select a.id
from a left outer join
     b
     on a.id = b.id2 
where (a.id > b.id or b.id2 is null);
```

However, your expression is only picking up the `id` from `a` and it is using a `left join`.  Hence, this is probably good enough:

```
select a.id
from a ;
```

Admittedly, it doesn't return the duplicates generated by the match to the `b` table, but duplicates are not usually desirable.

Comment: I suspect, so may be wrong, that this is an overly abstract representation of the actual requirement, just to demonstrate the problem using `>`.  The cause of which being their version of Hive doesn't support anything other than equality joins.